# Cyclical Thumping at Speed - 2007 Forester

Tags: brakes, noise, subaru, abs, forester

2007 Subaru Forester 2.5L EJ253 4EAT A/T @ 15xK miles

Strange cyclic thumping after 25/30mph. Worse when turning. Scraping/crappy noise when barely braking (Not the tattle-tale; checked. Pads are still like new.)

Stake failed, and axle nut came loose, axle cocked, and ground down the metal pin on the ABS sensor.

Heavy Brake dusting at that wheel, only. Heavy wear that rotor, only.

No idiot lights.

Bad rotor? Bad brake hose? Sticking caliper?

Action taken:

- New CV; with new ABS ring. New ring still in new condition after 2xx miles.
- Greased slides
- Unplugged ABS sensor
- Rotated tires

Suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you checked the wheel bearings?

Comment: Maybe a bad tire?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a wheel bearing. They will often sound like a distant helicopter when they are going. The reason the sound would change while turning is because you are taking weight on and off of the potentially bad bearing. Jack it up and check for play. Also spin it by hand and see if you can hear any resistance, grinding etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose this I have had to raise the driven wheels off the ground, disengage the traction control, and put the transmission in drive, then observe what is happening.  Of course, you have to take the necessary precautions to make sure the car cannot come off the supports or roll in any way; you must have level ground and the remaining wheels chocked if it's two wheel drive, which I don't think is the case with your Subaru.

Do not exceed 35MPH with the drive wheel tires unloaded, the centripetal acceleration without the load could cause a tire/wheel assembly failure -- and it could be pretty catastrophic, too.  If you aren't 100% certain you can do this safely, have a professional shop check it out; they'll put the car on a lift.

Use a mechanic's stethoscope to carefully probe each component and find the source of the noise.  If it is safe to do so, you might find a bad wheel bearing by touching the coil spring with your finger, but DO NOT touch the spinning wheel, and do not attempt doing this unless you have at least several inches of clearance.

I have also had some limited success with a set of "chassis ears" in finding problems like this.  Google for details.  It's a PITA and the tool is not inexpensive, but sometimes it's the only way to find something on an AWD vehicle when you don't have a lift.